# Switch from linux distro package manager to Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, opensuse

I am using openSUSE Leap 42.1 and do some data analysis work in python. Most of the python packages I use are available in the standard openSUSE repositories (e.g. obs://build.opensuse.org/devel:languages:python); however sometimes they aren't, whereas they are available in Anaconda. I would like to replace all of the python packages installed on my computer with those available through Anaconda.

Is it possible to just install Anaconda in parallel with the normal openSUSE packages or should I manually delete the packages I've installed? I know python is used heavily throughout the operating system so I probably don't want to deep clean the system of python before going the Anaconda route.

Has anyone done this before? I was unable to find any info on this on the Anaconda site, and I'm curious if there is a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the anaconda documentation, and there is no evidence of anaconda packages replacing your openSUSE packages. There isn't a reason for it to do so. If I got it right, then Conda is very similar to ruby's gem and similar tools, which definitely don't replace the installed packages. I think you can feel free to install it next to your current packages. Also, you can specify the python and python package version in the anaconda envinroments, which is another thing which it allows you to do, so you can decide what you will use there. Note, I'm not a conda user, this is how I understood the docs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious - did it help?

Comment: Howdy @chleboir, I installed Anaconda and appended the anaconda directory to my path. I'm guessing that since it's ahead of the other system packages, I should be good to go. The way I understand it, just like any other program, the system will use the first instance of a python module that matches the name it finds on the path.

Comment: You can specify the python version(and other packages version) when creating a conda environment. Not really sure, if it uses the newest version automatically, but if you use the environments, it should.
The docs for managing python versions : http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

Comment: Sorry, didn't tag you @cbcoutinho

Comment: I haven't completely tested to see if your solution causes any problems, but so far I was able to use the latest version of a package and that solved my problem. I set your answer as solved, thanks again!